# How to read HDD S.M.A.R.T. attributes?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, wmi, monitoring, zabbix

I would monitoring the smart HDD-s on my Windows 7 clients.

I would to get the HDD smart attributes without using any vbs file or ready-made tool just looking towards WMI or PowerShell.

I would aggregate that data with ZABBIX monitoring server (use `zabbix-sender.exe`).

I found a more or less solution for Linux, but I would monitor windows 7 machines HDD.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Use the WMI API to access SMART data like so,

```
gwmi -namespace root\wmi -class MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus
```

[There](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/san/archive/2011/08/11/have-you-ever-wanted-to-know-if-your-disk-is-going-to-fail-before-it-does.aspx) are more [examples](http://learn-powershell.net/2011/08/20/checking-for-failing-hard-drives-using-s-m-a-r-t-and-powershell/) in the net.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not provide enough informaiton.
I would get ID based vaues. Like
03 - spin_up_time 00

Answer (score 3):

--- **Preface:** ---

I believe that a PowerShell solution would meet your needs. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way of obtaining *all* S.M.A.R.T. information available from various storage devices via PowerShell only, as PowerShell's is a rather generic implentation of the functionality, and S.M.A.R.T. is varied in its implementation across storage device vendors.

Having said that, the method described below should satisfy the key requirements of typical S.M.A.R.T. checks performed by users, including predicted lifespan, reallocated and uncorrectable sectors, etc., though using rather generic PowerShell terminology (e.g. lifespan = "Wear").

--- **Information:** ---

With a combination of two PowerShell cmdlets, we can easily view some of the the S.M.A.R.T. data offered by storage devices:

[Get-StorageReliabilityCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-storagereliabilitycounter)

> "The **Get-StorageReliabilityCounter** cmdlet gets the storage reliability
>   counters for the specified disk or physical disk. These counters
>   include information about such things as the device temperature,
>   errors, wear, and length of time the device has been in use."

This is the cmdlet that will actually return the S.M.A.R.T data we seek. However, unlike many other cmdlets you may be familiar with, this cmdlet needs to be pointed to the target disk(s) by way of a PowerShell object(s). (If you're new to PowerShell, this is not as complex as it may sound, so fear not.)

[Get-Disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-disk)

> "The **Get-Disk** cmdlet gets one or more Disk objects visible to the
>   operating system, or optionally a filtered list."

This is the cmdlet we will use to provide the required PowerShell object(s), so that Get-StorageReliabilityCounter knows which disk(s) to query.

--- **Code:** ---

As with anything, there are multiple ways to actually execute the code, so I'm just going to provide code to obtain the desired information in the simplest way possible, in my opinion.

**For simple S.M.A.R.T. information on all local disks (run as Administrator):**

```
Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter
```

Sample output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter

DeviceId Temperature ReadErrorsUncorrected Wear PowerOnHours
-------- ----------- --------------------- ---- ------------
1                    0                     0    5505
2                    0                     0    572
0                                          0    2799
```

**For extended S.M.A.R.T. information on all local disks (run as Administrator):**

```
 Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object -Property "*"
```

Truncated sample output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object -Property "*"

DeviceId                : 1
FlushLatencyMax         : 46
LoadUnloadCycleCount    :
LoadUnloadCycleCountMax :
ManufactureDate         :
PowerOnHours            : 5505
ReadErrorsCorrected     : 0
ReadErrorsTotal         : 0
ReadErrorsUncorrected   : 0
ReadLatencyMax          : 231
StartStopCycleCount     :
StartStopCycleCountMax  :
Temperature             : 27
TemperatureMax          : 0
Wear                    : 0
WriteErrorsCorrected    :
WriteErrorsTotal        :
WriteErrorsUncorrected  :
WriteLatencyMax         : 69
PSComputerName          :
```

As you can see, listed are some of those desirable indicators that may or may not allow you to circumvent disaster.

--- **tl;dr:** ---

Run

```
Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter
```

or

```
Get-Disk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Select-Object -Property "*"
```

**as Administrator** to get most important S.M.A.R.T. information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a powershell script that extracts all the attribute data from smartctl (smartmontools) output. Adjust the path to smartctl if it's not in your %path%.

It can be used like this:

```
.\get-smart.ps1 -Drive hda -AttributeId 5,241 -Property Name,Raw -FriendlyOutput
```

or just

```
.\get-smart.ps1 hda 5,241 Name,Raw -f
```

etc. If you specify -FriendlyOutput it formats the data as table, otherwise it gives you an object.
If you're just interested in a specific value, use

```
.\get-smart.ps1 hda 241 Raw
```

Note that some properties, such as threshold, are not present if smartctl is not run as administrator.

No exception handling yet! You have been warned!

```powershell
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]    $Drive,
    [int[]]     $AttributeId,
    [string[]]  $Property,
    [switch]    $FriendlyOutput)
# parses attribute table in smartctl output and builds an object
$smart = [string[]](smartctl -A $Drive)
$attributes=@()
foreach ($s in $smart) {
    if ($s -match '^\s*(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([\d-]+)\s+([\w-]+)\s+(\w+)\s+([\w-]+)\s+(\d+)') {
        $o = new-object -Typename PSObject
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'ID' -value ([int]$matches[1])
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Name' -value $matches[2]
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Flag' -value $matches[3]
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Value' -value ([int]$matches[4])
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Worst' -value ([int]$matches[5])
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Threshold' -value ([int]$matches[6])
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Type' -value $matches[7]
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Updated' -value $matches[8]
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'WhenFailed' -value $matches[9]
        add-member -in $o -m NoteProperty -name 'Raw' -value ([int64]$matches[10])
        $attributes += $o
    }
}
if ($AttributeId){
    $attributes = $attributes | ? {$_.id -in $attributeid}
}
if ($Property){
    if ($property.count -gt 1 -and $attributes.count -gt -0 -and $Property -notcontains 'id'){
        # if more than one result and more than one attribute, add the ID to the output
        $property = ,'id'+$Property
    }
    $attributes = $attributes | select $Property
}
if (@($attributes).count -eq 1 -and @($attributes.psobject.properties).count -eq 1){
    # return single values directly instead of an object
    $attributes.psobject.properties.value
} elseif ($FriendlyOutput){
    $attributes | ft * -a
} else {
    $attributes
}
```

Comment: The complex (error prone) parsing script is no longer needed, just use the JSON output mode of smartctl.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JSON output mode of [Smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) this can be done easily:

The following short Powershell script read the SMART attributes for the first disk (named `/dev/sda` in smartmontools) and selects the attribute with ID 241 (that is `Total_LBAs_Written` on my SSD).

The last line converts the LBA value to the TBW value (**T**era**B**yte(s) **W**ritten).

```
$json = (smartctl -A -j /dev/sda | ConvertFrom-JSON)
$lbaRaw = ($json.ata_smart_attributes.table | Where id -eq 241 | Select-Object raw)
$tbw = $lbaRaw.raw.value * 512 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
$tbw.toString("##.## TB")
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets a useful view of the SMART values in one table, so you can map which drive has which values.

```
$Disks = Get-PhysicalDisk
$DiskTable = $Disks | Select-Object -Property FriendlyName,SerialNumber,UniqueId,FirmwareVersion,
    MediaType,Size,PhysicalSectorSize,LogicalSectorSize,
    @{Name="ReadErrorsCorrected";Expression={""}},@{Name="ReadErrorsUncorrected";Expression={""}},
    @{Name="ReadLatencyMax";Expression={""}},@{Name="WriteLatencyMax";Expression={""}},
    @{Name="Temperature";Expression={""}},@{Name="PowerOnHours";Expression={""}},
    @{Name="Wear";Expression={""}}
for ( $i=0 ; $i -lt $Disks.Count ; $i++ ) {
    $DiskReliability = $Disks[$i] | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | 
        Select-Object -Property ReadErrorsCorrected,ReadErrorsUncorrected,ReadLatencyMax,
            WriteLatencyMax,Temperature,PowerOnHours,Wear
    $DiskTable[$i].ReadErrorsCorrected = $DiskReliability.ReadErrorsCorrected
    $DiskTable[$i].ReadErrorsUncorrected = $DiskReliability.ReadErrorsUncorrected
    $DiskTable[$i].ReadLatencyMax = $DiskReliability.ReadLatencyMax
    $DiskTable[$i].WriteLatencyMax = $DiskReliability.WriteLatencyMax
    $DiskTable[$i].Temperature = $DiskReliability.Temperature
    $DiskTable[$i].PowerOnHours = $DiskReliability.PowerOnHours
    $DiskTable[$i].Wear = $DiskReliability.Wear
}
$DiskTable | Out-GridView
```